# Basic law of cosine problem

Tags: trigonometry

Question: In triangle ABC, if $a = 120$ cm, $b = 66$ cm, and $C = 120^\circ$, find $c$.

Applying the law of cosine:

$$c^2 = (120)^2 + (66)^2 - (2\cdot120\cdot66\cdot\cos120^\circ)$$

$$c^2 = 14400 + 4356 + 7920$$

$$c^2 = 26676$$

$$c = 6\sqrt{741}$$

Is this correct? Because my professor wrote down $c = 160$, I'm not sure if I made a mistake or if he wrote the answer down wrong.

Comment: Professor approximated the final answer. You're right! Well done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your professor probably approximated. The steps look right, and if you notice $\sqrt{26676} \approx 163.327891066$. So estimating $c=160$ seems more or less reasonable.

Comment: Thank you... I don't know why I didn't bother checking that.

Comment: @user234474 would you mind accepting this answer then? You will earn reputation, I will, and other users with a similar issue will see that this is the right answer.

Comment: Yeah, i'll do it in 6 minutes (It says wait 6 minutes)

Answer (score 1):

Your work is perfectly correct. Note that $6 \sqrt{741} \approx 163$, so it may be that your professor was just approximating the result with $160$.